# Insert the last date of last month in each cell of a range in a column

Tags: vba, date

I want a column (with a range) that shows the last date of the last month.

In May, I want 30/04/2022 in every cell from A3:A40.
In June, I want 31/05/2022 and so on.

Comment: Please, show us what you tried by your own. Even if it does not do what you want...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It should do what you need:

```
Sub testLastDayPrevMonthInRange()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastD As Date, refDate As Date
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = sh.Range("A3:A40")
    
    refDate = Date 'you may change it in any date to test the code...
    lastD = refDate - (Day(refDate))
    rng.value = lastD
End Sub
```

Please, next time you place a question you should show us a piece of code, like a prove that you made researches on your own. We here do not offer free code writing services... We only help people correcting their code problems and **learn**.